# How to Find a DataTable Row by Column Value Using LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, linq-to-objects, datarow

Hello I have a Dynamic DataTable Created at runtime. The Setup is like so

```
Id |  Name  | Age
-----------------
3  |  Mike  | 21
6  |  John  | 43
8  |  Sara  | 34
```

What I am trying to do is come up with a linq statement I could use to find and update specific rows.

Such as a statement to **change AGE to '33' WHERE ID = '3'**

My code So far is:

```
-[VB.NET]-
Dim MyRow As DataRow = From column In MyTable.Rows Where column("Id") = 3
MyRow(0)("Age") = 33
```

But this is not updating my DataTable entry. Any Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Mike, Consider one answer as your solution that solves your problem in best way and describe it well..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Take a look at:

```
Dim row As DataRow = (From column In MyTable.Rows Where column("Id") = 3).FirstOrDefault()
If Not IsNothing(row) Then
row("Age") = 33
End If
```

OR you may try DataTable.Select() method.

```
Dim rows=MyTable.Select("ID=3")
```

Comment: @Mike: Then you should [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/147438). Btw, the [Find-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=VS.100).aspx) is the fastest way to filter a DataTable by primary key.

Answer (score 2):

this is not `LINQ` but filtering datatable.

```
Dim iRow() As DataRow = ParticularSource.Tables(ParticularTable).Select(
    String.Format("ItemID = '{0}'", ParticularID))
```

`ParticularSource` is the name of my Dataset 
`ParticularTable` is the name of my Datatable 
`ItemID` is the field where I Searched on 
`ParticularID` is the value to be searched

```
iRow(0)("Age") = NewValue
ParticularSource.Tables(ParticularTable).AcceptChanges()
```